# Backward elimination for choosing the AR order

Tags: time-series, model-selection, autoregressive

Suppose that we are fitting an AR(p) model to the data (we have fixed the p).
Treating the AR(p) model as a multiple regression, we estimate all the parameters using OLS and then use the backward elimination method to toss out the insignificant lags.

I have checked a few standard time series textbooks and non of them treats the problem this way. I am new to the time series business, so I'd like to know if some thing is fundamentally wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, the backward elimination strategy would be a general-to-specific approach, which is fine, but is more commonly used in ARDL model selection.

Specific-to-general (or forward selection) is more common to ARMA modelling. However, most common are selection methods based on information criteria or some form of Box-Jenkins methodology.

There are pros and cons to each method.

For reference, this topic is briefly discussed in Chapter 7 (Section 7.5) of:

Judge, G. G., Hill, R. C., Griffiths, W., Lutkepohl, H., & Lee, T. C. (1985). The theory and practice of econometrics.

Comment: *based on information criteria* is partly tangential: both general-to-specific and specific-to-general, and more, can be done using information criteria.

Comment: @RichardHardy That's a good point!

Comment: Good idea, @RichardHardy. Yes, I'll vote for that. There's no vote button, though. How do I do it? Do I enter arma in the suggestion box? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, the vote is finished, and the synonym has been established.